# Advantage of introducing optional timeout parameter in latest version of imaplib

Tags: imaplib

What is the benefit of introducing the optional parameter 'timeout' in latest version of imaplib? Is it connection timeout or socket timeout?

Comment: `The optional timeout parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for the connection attempt`.  Does that not answer your question?  And it’s useful because some applications need precise control over how long they’re blocked trying to connect.

Comment: OK Thanks Max .But when I am introducing timeout  in code , I am getting socket timeout error.

Comment: Check your firewall.  Unless your server is very slow or the network is out, the timeout shouldn't be hit during normal use.  But many vhosts firewall email ports by default.